# Aligning a set of linear equations

Tags: equations, align

### Problem Description

I want to align the given system of equations at the equal sign and, if possible, also align at the sign of the variable. I also attempted to use [`systeme`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/systeme) too, but was unsuccessful.

Any help in getting this done would be much appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of the output, from the below compiled code.]

### MWE:

```
    $$
    \begin{matrix}
                               x     + 2y       - z        &= 1\\
                        2x   + 3y  + z         &= 1 \\   
    - 4x   -5 y + (h^2-9)z &= h + 1
   \end{matrix}
    $$
```

Answer (score 8):

> I used [the] `\systeme` command too but wasn't successful.

How about the following?

[image]

In the following code, note (a) the use of `[xyz]` to enforce a particular order of the variables and (b) the presence of `\` in `(h^2\-9)`; this instructs `systeme` *not* to use that instance of `-` as an alignment point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
\[
\sysdelim..
\systeme[xyz]{x+2y-z=1,2x+3y+z=1,-4x-5y+(h^2\-9)z=h+1}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Consider using `alignat` - it allows you to specify the alignment points wherever you want (with a right-left alignment around every `&`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
     x + {} && 2 y - {} &&        z &= 1     \\
   2 x + {} && 3 y + {} &&        z &= 1     \\   
  -4 x - {} && 5 y + {} && (h^2-9)z &= h + 1
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If no one else is going to suggest using `array`, I will.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

\[
  \arraycolsep=2pt% 1/2 gap for &
  \begin{array}{llll}
    x   & +2y & -z        & = 1\\
    2x  & +y  & +z        & = 1 \\   
    -4x & -5y & +(h^2-9)z & = h+1
   \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely certain what you want, in terms of the precise alignment of terms. Notwithstanding, I think that the fairly recent [`autoaligne`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/autoaligne) package can be used to accomplish this.

As an example, you can try modifying the below code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{autoaligne}

\begin{document}
\[
    \autoaligne{%
        +x    + 2y    +\-z          =+ 1\\
        +2x   + 3y   + z        =+ 1 \\   
        +\-4x + \-5y + (h^2-9)z = h + 1
        }%
\]
\end{document}
```

That produces the following output:

[image: A screenshot of the output produced by compiling the above LATeX code (with pdflatex).]